# CKAN requirements

Tags: solr, ckan

I currently have an installation of CKAN 2.5.2 using SolrCloud 6.1 with 5.5 versioned indexing. I am having a bit of difficulty tracking down the official Solr requirements for an installation of CKAN 2.6 and was hoping someone here would be able to help. Anyone here know the official "supported" version Solr/SolrCloud and the index version for CKAN 2.6, or have any experiences with such a setup? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stuart

You don't need to upgrade your Solr version or schema from 2.5.2 to 2.6.0 version. You can check more about it at http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/changelog.html

But you need to upgrade Python to 2.7 (or higher) and Postgres to 9.2 (or higher).